# Log4net and windows service. What else should I do to make this work

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

Please help me, I want to run log4net on my windows service. And it is simply - mission impossible.

First of all, with Win forms - work great.

Here is what I do with windows service:

Add to assembly:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

My config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="log-file.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c: %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

My class:

```
public class LogProvider
{
    private ILog _Log;


    public LogProvider(string className)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        _Log = LogManager.GetLogger(className);
    }

    public void Info(object message)
    {
        _Log.Info(message);
    }
}
```

And in main program:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

(...)

private LogProvider _logProvider;

(...)

                _logProvider = new LogProvider("Test");
                _logProvider.Info("asds");
```

WHAT IS GOING ON ?

If it possible, please show me sample project - because, this code above is about 100 version or more. I start to believe that this is impossible to use log4net using windows service.

---

UPDATE:

So, about permissions: 
Actually I get an exception, about permissions. I fix this with this line (requirePermission="false"):

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Now, It still not working, with no exception.

This is my final exec code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {

        LogProvider lp = new LogProvider("asd");
        lp.Info("asd2");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         System.IO.FileInfo _file;
         System.IO.StreamWriter _writer;
         _file = new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\Log\\asdCatch.txt");
         _writer = _file.CreateText();
         _writer.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] Init Log");
         _writer.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + ex.ToString());
         _writer.Close();

    }
}
```

Now I'm really confused, I've created another windows service and it's working - without that line with permission. OMG, this is weird.

---

UPDATE2:
OK, I've got it. I don't know how did this happened, but I found that line in my app.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

I'm working on 15-subproject program and seriously, I don't know where it came from:/

Comment: What do you observe? Is there an exception being thrown? Or does it simply not produce the output you'd expect?

Comment: it should log "asds" on start. There is no new file. I tried in C:\\ i D:\\ in {tmp}, direct in my dir app..

Comment: No crash or exception then. Have you considered using procmon (SysInternals tool) to watch your windows service? It will show you any file system access.

Comment: I think I have to. I don't use any program to watch my windows service. Unless, there is a sample project with windows service and log4net somewhere ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had a problem because the services runtime directory is `C:\Windows\System` or `C:\Windows\System32`. Therefore the log4net.config has to be in your system dir which is not desirable or you have to provide the path to your log4net.config file.

Comment: This was the same case for me. I just merged log4net config with app.config file.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely if this logging is working in a windows application it is a **permissions issue**.  When you are logging in a windows service the user that the windows service is running under must have write permissions to the folder you are trying to log to.

Also you should try enabling log4net debugging to see if this helps you.

```
<log4net debug="true">

    ... configuration ...

</log4net>
```

You should also look at my answer in a post very similar to this if there are additional questions:

[log4net doesn't create log file when deployed on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622897/log4net-doesnt-create-log-file-when-deployed-on-iis7/14626523#14626523)

Comment: But from win forms - work good. How to set permission from C# ?

Comment: Cole is implying the account the windows service is running under does not have permissions to write to the folder to wherever you are logging to.  So if that folder was C:\MyLogs  the user the windows service is running under has to have write permissions on that folder.  You will not be able to grant permissions to a folder via C# code in your windows service for the user the service is running under.  If they don't have permissions prior to the service trying to write log there, it will not log.

Comment: Best answer! I put debug="true" and I was seeing what exactly wrong with my config.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with log4net + windows service, you can you enable log4net internal debugging (http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug) and run your service in console mode to view any possible misconfiguration

try this as well:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config", Watch = true)]
```