# How to Log output in a webservice run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, logging

Someone (not me) developed a web site that hits a web service implemented in C#. When I run the web site in visual studio, the project automatically starts the web service. In the web service, I want to log some information to a file for testing. log4net is used in the webservice project, but nothing is logged. I will admit I do not spend much time dealing with log4net, but the web.config hsa values that look like they should produce a file, and it does not.

So, I tried to dump the text of interest to a text file on my local drive.

```
File.AppendAllText(logPath, txt + "\n");
```

There are no errors and nothing is sent to the file.

I start the Website, not the web service, so the debugger seems to not know about the web service (so I can't simply set a break point in the web service).

My expectation is that for security reasons things are started in a way that simply disallow this. I vaguely remember that when started in this way, your services are also not allowed to write to disk, so in a development box while running from visual studio, how can I write a simple file to disk.

It seems to me like this should be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers were useful, and correct, it is not what solved the issue. Also, related, see this:

[log4net doesn't create log file when deployed on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622897/log4net-doesnt-create-log-file-when-deployed-on-iis7)

Remember that I chose to start the WebSite, and that auto-starts the WebService. That problem has NOT been solved, but, a coworker burned some brain cells and he thinks that it has to do with how Visual Studio magically starts the web service and that log4net is NOT initialized. If I start the web service by itself, then logging works as configured.  I am still testing to see if the above advice allows a lot to be written to a specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

First at all, you should call the web service, to log anything. You could use an external program like fiddler or postman, or write a unit test. After the first call, you could attach the visual studio to the w3wp.exe, so you could debug the problem.

The user of the AppPool should be granted the write permission to the log file.

Comment: I have limited experience in this domain and I did not create this project, but that person is no longer available. I tell Visual Studio to start the web site project. Visual studio starts the web service automatically (it is part of the global project). What user is used? In other words, how do I set that user to have write permission? In production, this is easier (not that I really know the production environment) because things are started individually and I just want some test output.

Answer (score 1):

I want to comment at the above answer,but i have no rights.

To set that user to have write permission, for local develop environment,just right click the log folder ,select properties,under the "security" tab,click "Edit",add "EveryOne" with read,write,modify permissions.

In production  environment,you should select the real apppool user instead.