# Log4net is not logging to the file on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, log4net

I used Log4net to log errors. The logger will work fine and Log Only My Actions "I think because I am the creator. But for IIS User, the logger will not log any action from my site.

My Web config:

```
<configSections>
            <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
            <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
</configSections>

    <log4net debug="true">
        <appender name="rega_appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

            
            <file value="E:\Logger\" />
            <datePattern value="'Rega_logger_.log_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />

            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
                <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %-5level %type.%method (%line) [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <level value="All" />
            <appender-ref ref="rega_appender" />
        </root>
        <!--<logger name="Rega_Logger">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="rega_appender" />
    </logger>-->
    </log4net>
```

GLobal.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        }
```

assembliyinfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And I called it like this:

```
 private static readonly ILog RegaLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

public void info(){
  RegaLogger.Error("CRM Error. Data:" + model);
}
```

The code is reachable, but it is not logging to file.
I gave IIS_USer Write permission, but still not working.

Comment: Is the log file created? You need to be aware the writing to the log doesn't happen immediately. You can force it by restarting your IIS Application Pool. Also inspect Windows Event Logs - permission related issues will show up there.

Comment: Yes, the file will be created, but there will be no logs, even when I check after one day

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622897/log4net-doesnt-create-log-file-when-deployed-on-iis7