# Log4net works in one project but not another

Tags: c#, log4net

I am having trouble getting log4net working in one of my projects.

This project is a Windows Service that I have set to output to a Console Application.

I have a `log4net.config` file in the root of the project and it is set to `Copy Always`.

In my `AssemblyInfo.cs`, I have the following line at the bottom of the file:
`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

However, nothing gets logged.

The only way I was able to get the logging to work was by adding this into the `Main` method:
`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("log4net.config"));`

I have another project (console application) with the same setup, using `AssemblyInfo.cs` and the logging works perfectly there with no configuration inside the `Main` method.

What could I be missing here?

`log4net.config`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <log4net>
      <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>

      <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file ty

pe="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\CommerceCloudDev\agent-scheduler.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

`AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Comment: This part looks good. Could you show the contents of your configuration file.

Comment: Have attached.. however I don't think its the config file - it appears to not be loaded when I use the attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs as I can put any malformed text in it and I get no exception.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is a working directory issue. Windows Services have Windows\System32 directory as a working directory, so it may be looking for this file there, instead of its binary folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4net and windows service. What else should I do to make this work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918224/log4net-and-windows-service-what-else-should-i-do-to-make-this-work)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that makes sense. Why would it work when configuring from the Main method but not in AssemblyInfo?

Comment: I couldn't find why :) May be, it is implemented differently for attribute and programmatic loading. You may want to review the source code or read through some issues at their [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4NET/issues).

Comment: @Lock Have you found any solution to this. As I am facing same issue, it's just that I am on WPF application which logs from startup project and not from other project which uses static class implemented in common(Non startup) project. I am not able to find out the root cause. Can you please help?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was from 5 years ago and I can't remember if it was resolved or not - was at a different company.